# How do you arrive at this equation? $ \bar{v} = v_2 - \tfrac{1}{2} a \Delta t $

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

$$ \bar{v} = v_2 - \tfrac{1}{2} a \Delta t $$

$\bar{v}$ being average velocity and $v_2$ instantaneous velocity at one point

this equation was used to find instantaneous velocity from average velocity in a  $\bar{v}$ vs $t$ graph, $v_2$ being the intercept in that graphic.

As $\Delta t$ tends to zero the the average velocity tends to the instantaneous velocity.

What I don't understand is where this equation came from.

I was told this equation was obtained through integrals.

Comment: Hint: This formula is valid for constant acceleration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We define the average value of a quantity by :
$$ \langle v \rangle=\frac{\displaystyle\int_{t_0}^{t} v ~\mathrm dt}{\displaystyle\int_{t
_0}^{t} ~\mathrm dt} \ .$$

Now using the first equation of motion we get:
$$v=u+at$$

Putting this in the integral we get:
$$\langle v \rangle =\frac{\displaystyle\int_{t_0}^{t}(u+at)~\mathrm dt}{t-t_0}$$

which simplifies to $$\langle v \rangle =v+\frac{1}{2}a(t-t_0)\ ,$$ provided $a$ is constant.

Comment: When you are using $v= u+ at ,$ it's _implied_ that $a=\text{const.}$

Comment: yes, that's implied, I just provided a line at the end for clarity.

Comment: why does your equation have a positive sign  and my equation a negative one?

Comment: Maybe because of your limits on $t$, or maybe your case is a deceleration.